# What are those devices in Ghost in the Shell they use to arrest suspects?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell

What are those devices in Ghost in the Shell they use to arrest suspects? It seemingly causes them to be paralyzed from the neck down.

I think I saw in mentioned in the manga, but not the anime.

Comment: This is what characters refer to a [ghost key](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18371/what-is-this-ghost-infiltration-key). You see it appears toward the end of chapter 3 in the original manga.

Answer (score 2):

It is in chapter three of the manga:

[image: manga pg 94]

Apparently in the manga, it renders them unconcious, but their bodies can still be moved, but in the anime, they become temporarily quadriplegic.

Comment: Similar device is in Innocence, although it appears to have a pistol grip interface, a la certain scene involving Batou in a convenience store.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a wiki entry or anything like that, but from what I've seen (and I've seen all of GITS a few times) it's a special device to paralyze people or any other thing that has this port.

I don't remember any explanation about how it works, it just does. Section 9 uses it often enough throughout the years to assume it's reliable.

[image]
<sub>An image of the neck port and a connection wire. Didn't find a paralyzing plug pic, so if somebody does, please edit it in.</sub>